# SSRS 2008 row visibility issue

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I am facing following scenario :
I have two values A and B and I need to Hide and show it based on ssrs expression.
My Conditions :

1. If A = 1 and B = 1 show row
2. If A = 1 and B = 0 Show row
3. If A = 0 and B = 1 Show row
4. If A = 0 and B = 0 Hide Row

(I have tried using AND, OR, XOR, AndAlso, OrElse but it is not working.)
**(Problem arises because SSRS shows when output is false and hides when output is true)**

Comment: This should be as simple as setting hidden to `A = 0 And B = 0`. You might have abstracted out the real problem from your question when simplifying it?

Comment: Based on two column values I have to set visibility of row.

Comment: @Azhar Can you show your expressions tried? The one suggested above should work.

Comment: =IIF((Fields!A.Value = 0) AND (Fields!B.Value = 0),False,True)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the table detail row (or group row depending your table) and in the Visibility set the hidden expression like below

= ( Fields!A.Value = 0 AND Fields!B.Value = 0)